# Using get() and set() in Java

Tags: java

I have seen several get() and set() methods used for private fields. And I also understand why its being used.

But what I dont understand is that, I have my `Student` class with private fields in them. So why is it when I remove the get() and set(), it still works (for example, method to print).

Or is it still working because its in the same file class? but say if I try calling the private field without defining the get() and set() method from an external class. It wont work?

This is my code with the get() and set()

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String degreeName;
    private String department;
    private String yearCommence;
    private long studentID;
    private static int nextID = 901000 ;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public String getDegreeName() {
        return degreeName;
    }
    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }
    public String getYearCommence() {
        return yearCommence;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.name = address;
    }
    public void setDegreeName(String degreeName) {
        this.degreeName = degreeName;
    }
    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }
    public void setYearCommence(String yearCommence) {
        this.department = yearCommence;
    }

    public Student(String name, String address, String degreeName, String department, String yearCommence, long StudentID) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.degreeName = degreeName;
        this.department = department;
        this.yearCommence = yearCommence;
        this.studentID = nextID++;
    }

    public Student(String name, String address, String degreeName, String department, long studentID) {
        this(name, address, degreeName, department, null, studentID);
    }
    public Student(String name, String address, String degreeName, long studentID) {
        this(name, address, degreeName, null, null, studentID);
    }
    public Student(String name, String address, long studentID) {
        this(name, address, null, null, null, studentID);
    }
    public Student(String name, long studentID) {
        this(name, null, null, null, null, studentID);
    }
    public Student(long studentID) {
        this(null, null, null, null, null, studentID);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "StudentInfo {" + "name=" + name + ", address=" + address + ", degreeName=" + degreeName + ", department=" + department + ", commence = " + yearCommence +", "+ " "+ "studentID = " + studentID+ "}";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

        Student student1 = new Student("Yusuf", "jl.ANU", "IT", "CECS", null, Student.nextID);
        students.add(student1);
        System.out.println(student1);

        Student student2 = new Student("Ning", "jl.Cikini","IT", null, null, Student.nextID);
        students.add(student2);
        System.out.println(student2);

        Student student3 = new Student("Boris", "jl.Babi", Student.nextID);
        students.add(student3);
        System.out.println(student3);

        Student student4 = new Student(null, null, null, null, null, Student.nextID);
        students.add(student4);
        System.out.println(student4);
    }
}
```

Comment: *but say if I try calling the private field without defining the get() and set() method from an external class. It wont work?* Why you do not try it?

Comment: " is it still working because its in the same file class ?" : Yes exactly .

Comment: *So why is it when I remove the get() and set(), it still works (for example, method to print).* yes it works because of they are in the same class

Comment: name, address, etc are all members of the class, you can access those without a getter setter too

Comment: Note that you are not using the id parameter in the constuctor. You access directly the private static field (as you should by the way, let the class update it itself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your functions are in the class that owns the private attributes and can therefore access all of them without needing a getter function. It should also be noted that because the `main` function is `static` it can only access other `static` members.

Comment: That's not completly true. The main method of this class isn't able to change any of theses private fields, because this method is static and therefor it can only access attributes which are also static for this class

Comment: @ZeusNet I think it's quite clear the answer is implying all _member_ methods have access to private member variables, so your comment is silly.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I agree with you that this is obvious for people which are familiar with java but for others it could be confusing.

Comment: so say this class doesnt have the main method. And I have another class which have a main method. Therefore, that class with the main method will used access fields and attributes through the get() and set() from the `Student` class?

Comment: @Butola Yes, the other class won't be able to access the private fields directly and you will need the get methods.

Comment: I moved the main function into another file. So now its not working with the error message `nextID has private access` but Ive made the get() and set() as follow: `public int getNextID(){
        return nextID;
    }` and `public void setNextID(int nextID){
        this.nextID = nextID;
    }` so why is it not working eventhough Ive made the get() and set() in the student class for accessing it?

Comment: If your get methods are `public` and you replaced your `Student.nextId` with `Student.getNextID()` it should be working as long a you are calling the method on an instanciated object. If you want to call it on the `Student` class you need to make the get/set methods `static`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, Ive change the `Student.nextID` to `Student.getNextID()` but this is the error message now `Error:(11, 86) java: non-static method getNextID() cannot be referenced from a static context`

Comment: Oh I changed the get() method into static in the Student class and it worked. Is it because I set the field in the Student class `private static int nextID = 901000` so I set it static, therefore I have to make the get() method static aswell in order for other class from external file be able to call it. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Non static methods need an object instance to be called. Here, you are calling the get method on the Student class, which is not the same as a Student object, and therefore you only have access to static methods.

Answer (score 0):

Private attributes are, by definition, only accessible by the same class. This means that methods in the class itself can access the private attributes. Methods in any other classes won't be able to access such private attributes and thus would need get/set methods.

Answer (score 0):

There can be private fields in an class which have no get or set method. Your are able to use your class, but can't set or get the values of this fields from outside this class. If you have a constructer which have these private fields as parameters, these fields will be set on initialization, but can't be change afterwards on that instance.

Answer (score 0):

It work mostly because you never used those getter/setter.

You create the instances and call `toString` on it (not directly, but `System.out.println` will do it)

But, let say you had another class where you build an instance `Student student = new Student...`. And you have :

```
student.name = name; //This is directly accessing the private field "name"
stuendt.setName(name); //This is using the setter of "name"
```

Java will not translate a direct access of the variable into a call of the getter/setter by itself, you have to do it. You can't expect the JVM to call `setName` if you write the first line.

---

For the scope where those values are accessible, I let you read the others answers. Don't need to say it one more time.

---

Please note that you are note using the parameter for the ID

```
public Student(String name, String address, String degreeName, String department, String yearCommence, long StudentID) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.degreeName = degreeName;
    this.department = department;
    this.yearCommence = yearCommence;
    this.studentID = nextID++;
}
```

You still use `nextID` insteand of `StudentID`. Personnaly, I would not ask for that parameter if I am using a static value directly. You could simply remove it from the parameters list.

Answer (score -1):

private fields are accessible from the same class. If you want the fields to be accessed from external class then you should declare the variable with public modifier.

You are over riding toString() method in your student class which is executed every time you print the object.

mutators and accessors are used to set the read/write behavour for the fields(from external).

I suggest you to look on access modifiers in java.

Comment: May I know why the negative?